# Not able to run jhbuild:Error executing command as another user: Not authorized

Tags: command-line, authentication, jhbuild

I am running

```
jhbuild sysdeps --install
```

After running this command it is asking for authentication:

```
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.policykit.exec ===
Authentication is needed to run `/usr/bin/apt-get' as the super user
Multiple identities can be used for authentication:
```

After choosing one user and giving correct password it is showing this error:

```
Choose identity to authenticate as (1-2): Invalid response `'.
==== AUTHENTICATION CANCELED ===
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized
```

I have referred to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1077546 also.
I am not able to fix this issue. Please suggest something.